# How do I find out who owns a Microsoft Software key?

Tags: license, license-key, volume-license

Some of the machines at the office where I work have copies of Microsoft software installed on them, but they were installed a long time ago, and there's no indication of who or what MVLC account was used to install them originally.

Using an existing license key obtained from the installed software, is it possible to find out which MVLC account is associated with the software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the info from just the key itself? No, at least not that I'm aware of. :)

Can you look it up?  Yes:

- Log into MS's [Volume Licencing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).
- Click **View Relationship Summary** (Or from the menu: Licences->Relationship Summary).
- This will give you a list of all volume licenses associated to you.*
- Click on one of the **Licensing IDs**.
- Click the **Product Keys** tab, and search (by using alt-f in your browser for example) for your key.
- Repeat for each of the licences you have associated, until you find the key you're looking for.

*If you are missing any licenses from that list, you'll have to request association using the License and Authorization numbers from the volume/open license sheet MS (and/or your OEM) sent you when you bought them.  Once you have that info, click "Add an Open License to your profile" on that page to get it associated to your profile.

Comment: Well we have two accounts that all have licenses and we've been meaning to merge them somehow, so that sounds like a great way to do it.